# How to use OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, python-import

I have just installed OpenCV on my Windows 7 machine. As a result, I get a new directory:

`C:\OpenCV2.2\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages`

In this directory, I have two files: `cv.lib` and `cv.pyd`.

Then I try to use the `opencv` from Python. I do the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\OpenCV2.2\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages')
import cv
```

As a result I get the following error message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**ADDED**

As it was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195441/opencv-2-0-and-python), I have copied content of `C:\OpenCV2.0\Python2.6\Lib\site-packages` to the `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages`. It did not help.

**ADDED 2**

My environment variables have the following values:

```
Path=C:\Program Files\MiKTex\miktex\bin;C:\OpenCV2.2\bin;C:\Python26;
PYTHONPATH=C:\OpenCV2.2\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages
```

Do I need to change something? Do I need to add something?

**ADDED 3**

I think my question is general: How to use a library? Probably I need to find a *.ddl file somewhere? Then I need to use the name of the directory containing this file as a value to some environment variables? Or maybe I need to use `sys.addpath`? I also need to know how the way to call the library is related to the name of the file that contains the library.

**ADDED 4**

It is interesting that when I type `import cv`, I get:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

But when I type `import opencv` I get:

```
ImportError: No module named opencv
```

**ADDED 5**

It has been suggested that I usthe e inconsistent version of python. In more details, OpenCV tries to use Python2.7 and I had Python2.6. So, I have installed Python 2.7. It makes difference. Now I do not have the old error message, but I have a new one:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

**ADDED 6**

I have managed to resolve the problem by installing numpy. It took some time because I did not realized that there are different numpy installer corresponding to different versions of Python. Some details can be found in my answer to my own question (see bellow).

Comment: have you tried to export your python library path?

Comment: @ardiyu07, no. How can I do it?

Comment: export PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH=~/projects/opencv/release/lib:$PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I tried to execute it in the command line and got: 'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: export is only for posix environment, so you cannot execute it in command prompt, i thought you were using cygwin or mingw for the python ide..

Comment: According to your second addition, OpenCV thinks you have Python 2.7 while you appear to be using Python 2.6. Maybe it helps if you exclusively use 2.6 or 2.7?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709301/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was resolved. The following steps has been done:

1. A new version of python (version 2.7) has been installed.
2. After that I still was unable to run OpenCV because I had some problems with the numpy library.
3. I tired to install numpy but the installer did not see my new version of the Python.
4. I deleted the old version of Python as well as links to the old version in the Path system vatriable.
5. After that numpy installer was not able to finish the installation.
6. I have realized that I need to run another numpy installer that is associated with the Python 2.7. It can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.5.1/numpy-1.5.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download).
7. Finally everything worked. I was able to "import cv".

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you have the same problem I've run into.  If you have a 64-bit version of Python, it cannot load 32-bit DLLs.  OpenCV currently only ships 32-bit binaries.  If you want 64-bit .pyd and .dll files, you have to compile them yourself.  There are some [instructions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B) on the OpenCV Wiki, but it's not for the faint of heart.  Expect to have a substantial time investment.

The easiest solution is to:

1. Uninstall 64-bit Python
2. Install a 32-bit distribution.

The PythonXY distribution includes pyopencv -- a good set of OpenCV hooks.  The only limitation is that it's 32-bit, so don't make plans to process gigapixel astronomy data with it!  ;)

If you *must* have the 64-bit version, follow [these instructions](http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/) to get it OpenCV to compile with Visual Studio 2010.  There's a discussion on stackoverflow that describes building 64-bit apps with VC Express.

**EDIT:** OpenCV now ships with 64-bit Python binaries.  The .dll files need to go somewhere in your path (I put them in the scripts folder), and the .pyd files go in your site-packages directory.

Comment: There is a set of "unofficial" Windows binaries at [UC Irvine](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) which are working for me under 64-bit Python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.8. I realize that not everyone is comfortable running binaries that someone else has built, but at the point where I was faced with uninstalling 64-bit Python or doing my own compiles, I decided to give these a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @mcduffe.  OpenCV now also ships with 64-bit Python libraries too.  I'll update my response.

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble interfacing OpenCV with Python, and I was looking all over the place for help. Here's what worked for me. I basically followed this post: http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/install-opencv-in-windows-for-python.html. After downloading and extracting OpenCV 2.4.6, you basically get a folder called "opencv" with a bunch of stuff in it. Navigate to build->python->2.7. Inside, there is only one file called "cv2.pyd". I copied this file and pasted it in "python-2.7.5\Lib\site-packages". I'm actually using the Spyder IDE, and it works fine. In the python interpreter, typing in "import cv" worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks! Except that I'm on a 64-bit windows, so I had a 64-bit Anaconda spyder distribution. So when I pasted cv2.pyd and imported it, it gave an error of some invalid 32-bit DLL file. So I installed the 32-bit Anaconda Spyder, and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should edit your environment variable
right click on the "My Computer" or something like this, click on properties.

In the properties window click on the Advanced tab.
Then, the environment variables button.

Change the path.

Comment: I thought about that but I do not know what value should I assign to what variable.

Comment: variable: PATH, adding like this PATH= yourvalue:OLDPATH, about the value, I think it's the path to the dll directory. not sure though

Comment: `PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH`, not `PATH`. `PATH` is the the path that's searched for executable files. I.e. if you want to open up a terminal (cmd window) and type `whatever`, the folders specified in `PATH` will be searched to find executable files named `whatever`. However, this looks more like a problem with mixing python versions... You appear (?) to have installed opencv for python2.6 and are trying to run it from your python2.7 install, so changing environment variables is unlike to help you.