# What are the PYTHONPATH and PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: python, import, path, environment-variables, pythonpath

I have installed a package and cannot get it to work. I know that one of the possible reasons of this problem is incorrect (or not existing) values of certain environment variables. In particular, I know that I need to set `PYTHONPATH`  and `PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH`. To set the correct values for these variables I need to know their meaning.

For example, after the installation of the package, I got a directory with a lot of *.dll files. Should I use the name of this directory as a value for one of the two above mentioned environment variables?

I also have another directory (`C:\OpenCV2.2\Python2.7\Lib\site-packages`) that contains just two files: `cv.lib` and `cv.pyd`. Should I use this directory as a value for one of the above mentioned environment variables (people recommend that but I do not understand why).

Answer (score 3):

- [`PYTHONPATH` is documented](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)
- `PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH` is something I never heard of. That variable is not set in my environment and is not mentioned in the entire documentation. I also searched the entire python source code and that string is also not mentioned there. Where did you see about this variable? Maybe it is some vendor-specific thing?

Comment: Looks like PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH is an OpenCV-project specific build variable. See their install guide: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

Comment: People mention PYTHON_LIBRARY_PATH here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030362/how-to-use-opencv-in-python/5057423#5057423