# windows, ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, opencv, numpy, dll

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('12.jpg',0)
orb = cv2.ORB()
kp = orb.detect(img,None)
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()
```

I have added the `numpy` and `cv2` modules to my python directory and set their environment variables.

I also installed `msvcp71.dll` and `msvcr71.dll`, but this error has not solved.

So how can i fix this kind of dll problem?

Version information:

1. Python 3.2
2. numpy-1.6.1-win32-superpack-python3.2
3. opencv-3.0.0

Comment: How did you install numpy and OpenCV? What directory did you add them to, and what exactly did you add? What environment variables did you set? Please [edit] your question and add **all** of the relevant details. We can't read your mind, and have no idea what you actually did. Additionally, please add the **full text** of the traceback to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use OpenCV in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030362/how-to-use-opencv-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you've mixed a **x64** `python` with **x86** `cv2.pyd` file, or vice versa. Simple way is to install a right version of opencv here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

See discussions here:

1. [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. But the DLL's are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls)
2. [How to use OpenCV in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030362/how-to-use-opencv-in-python)

To check your `python` arch:

```
In [2]: import platform

In [3]: platform.architecture()
Out[3]: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

and `cv2.pyd`:
I suggest using [PESnoop](http://www.prestosoft.com/download/plugins/PESnoop.zip):

```
D:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages> PESnoop cv2.pyd /pe_dh
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PESnoop 2.0 - Advanced PE32/PE32+/COFF OBJ,LIB command line dumper by yoda
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Dump of file: cv2.pyd...
Modus:        64bit Portable Executable Image...
```

discussions:

> https://serverfault.com/questions/29958/how-to-tell-if-a-windows-application-requires-64-bit
>
> [How can I determine for which platform an executable is compiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197951/how-can-i-determine-for-which-platform-an-executable-is-compiled/198009)

Comment: I checked both of my files and they are 64 bit. Do you have another idea on why this is happening?

Comment: @roi.holtzman do you have multiple versions of *py* or *opencv* on your os? maybe you started pyA and checked pyB etc....

Comment: @roi.holtzman you may ask a new question and post your detailed trials.