# 'ImportError: DLL load failed' when fetching MNIST original via sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, windows-10, importerror, mnist

I am working on a Win10 PC with Python 3.5.4 64-bit and currently I am testing a jupyter notebook inside virtualenv.

The following code causes the error:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata("MNIST original")
mnist
```

This is the complete error message:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

Or in English:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So far I've found several Stackoverflow threads and other posts with the same error message and all kind of Python packages. Usually a mixture of x86 and x64 installations (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671918/windows-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030362/how-to-use-opencv-in-python)) gets blamed, but everything seems to be fine with my installation.
I already fully reinstalled Python, but I still get the same error...

Is there any way to check what might cause this error?

Comment: Before encountering this issue I was unable to install scipy using 'pip install --upgrade scipy', so I had to download a version ('scipy-1.0.0b1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl') and install this one. Might this cause the trouble?

Comment: Yes (this is beta after all; despite the recommendation). The painless way would be using anaconda. Read scipy's install docs for alternatives.

Comment: @sascha After giving the Ubuntu Bash for Windows a try (which did not want to install jupyter nor matplotlib), I turned to anaconda and for now it works just fine. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue with loading of different types of data-sets but with Tensorflow. The easiest way to solve is to uninstall your previous Python 3.5/3.6.x and install the `latest Python 3.6.6 (as of now) unless 3.7 is supported officially`.

`Also remember to delete your old python site packages from appdata in Windows. Althrough it won't obstruct with your new python installation but its a good way to clear off your old Python installed packages.`