# where is opencv python located in windows?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, darknet, darkflow

I have installed opencv on windows machine and need to have opencv folder in C drive separately(not inside any other folder)  but can't find folder in which it is installed. please help me.

Comment: show this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030362/how-to-use-opencv-in-python)

Comment: Use the search feature your OS comes with.

Comment: `import cv2` `print(cv2.__file__)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably with all modules you can use `__file__` to find it on disk

```
import cv2 

print(cv2.__file__)
```

`cv2` has also special variabel with path to `.xml` files used to recognize faces - it can be also useful.

```
print(cv2.data.haarcascades)
```